# Extract and return object from a Single in rxjava

Tags: rx-java

I have the next method, which returns a Single:

```
override fun getNavItemById(dCSServiceContext: DCSServiceContext):Single<NavItem>{
        return scribeProvider.getNavItemById(dCSServiceContext).map{ navItem ->
            return@map scribePresenter.presentNativeItem(navItem)
        }
    }
```

But I like that this method return just the object, something like:

```
override fun getNavItemById(dCSServiceContext: DCSServiceContext):NavItem{
        return scribeProvider.getNavItemById(dCSServiceContext).map{ navItem ->
            return@map scribePresenter.presentNativeItem(navItem)
        }// I need just the object in order to pass this result as a parameter to other method
    }
```

Any ideas of how an elegant way to do this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: change the return type of `scribePresenter.presentNativeItem(navItem)` or use `Single.blockingGet()` (although try to avoid these sort of rx blocking methods)

Comment: The scribePresenter.presentNativeItem(navItem) is returning a NavItem, and it is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

adding `.blockingGet()` to the end of your stream should do the trick. It will return the actual value instead of Single

It should look something like this

```
return scribeProvider.getNavItemById(dCSServiceContext)
.map { navItem -> return@map scribePresenter.presentNativeItem(navItem) 
}.blockingGet()
```

Comment: There is a way to achieve this without using blocking call? I am working with async calls

Comment: Yes, just change the method signature to return void an pass a listener as an extra parameter in the method and subscribe to the observable and emmit the value back through the listener